# Adding the value of a variable to a database field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database table called `submission` with a field called `points` with a type of `bigint(100)`.

On a PHP file, I have a variable called `$commentpoints` with a numerical value.

In the PHP file, how could I add `$commentpoints` to `points`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of adding it in your SQL update query:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE submissions
    SET points = points + ' . (int) $commentpoints . '
    WHERE id = ' . (int) $id;
```

That will add the value of `$commentpoints` to the points in the database; just make sure to use the where clause so you don't add it to every record in the submissions table.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table SET points = '[your value]'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE submission SET points = '$commentpoints'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "UPDATE submission
        SET points = points + ?
            WHERE commentid=?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($commentpoints,$commentid));
```